# Joomla: Is it possible to link a module to an alternate layout

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a template that needs to include a section in the header on some pages. I could use a module for this. But in only shows up on some pages, and that needs to be determined at article level. So "article a" would have the extra content and "article b" would not. I don't like the idea of a hidden menu because there could potentially be thousands of these articles and it requires an extra step for the authors. It seems like the best solution might be an alternate layout, which could be selected while creating or editing the article. So the question is, how can I turn the module on and off based on the alternate layout? Can I get the value of the alternate layout and do something with that (call a file with the same name for instance)?

EDIT: At this point I am simply trying to determine if an alternate layout is in use and if it is, what it is named. I am trying to access this in a template override (templates/mytemplate/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where I've ended up.

To get the alternate layout I do this:

```
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load(JRequest::getInt("id"));
    $attribs=new JParameter($article->attribs);
    $layout=$attribs->get("article_layout");
```

Now I can reference a file that includes anything special I want to do for this layout like so:

```
        if($layout != ''){
            $layoutname=str_replace($this->template . ':', '', $layout);
            $path=JPATH_ROOT .'/templates/'. $this->template .'/html/com_content/article/' . $layoutname . '_include.php';      
            require_once $path;
        }
```

Any layouts that require additional sections just needs another file named alternate_layout_name_include.php in the folder with the other alternate layout files.

I am not great with Joomla or php, so any tips, code modifications, input is always welcome.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, but I would still like to know if it is the best solution and the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust module for all pages (adjust on some position), and in template add some rule for hiding this position from template
for example:

```
<?php if($articleID == 1){?><jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" /><?php}?>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying not to do. There could end up being many, many articles and I would have to add the $articleID==x each time one was added. I want the author to have the ability to do it. I want to show/hide it based on a alternate layout selection. What I really need is the current layout. How can I get at that info?

Comment: If you about layout (view) of template you can do it in such way
$getData = new JInput($_GET);
$template = $getData->get('template','','string);//template of site
$view = $getData->get('view','','string);//view of component
$tmpl = $getData->get('tmpl','','string);//additional layout, for example 'component'
in module you can get value of template from $params
$layout = $params->get('layout', 'default');
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_test', $layout ); - in such way you can change template